# Select Box Show div on change

Tags: javascript

I have a select box that directs users to another page when an item is selected. I would like to show some kind of loading.gif when the user selects an Item, so they know that something is happening. Can someone please show me how to accomplish this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>


        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("sRedirect").change(function(){
   $("#sRedirect :selected").not(:contains('Click Here To Select')).siblings("img").first().attr('src','loading.gif');
});


</script>

 </head>
<body>

        <div class="titleBar">
            <div class="Logo"><a class ="backBtn" href="javascript:history.back();">    </a><img src="logotop.png"  align="right" />
                    </div>









<br><br>
    <div class="top"><br><br><h2>Step 1<br><br>Choose an Area</h2><br><br>    <div>
    <div class="middle">




<form name=form1>

<select name="URL" id="sRedirect" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value"    onfocus="javascript:toggle();" >
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Click Here To Select</option>
    <?=$options?>
    </SELECT>
<br>
<img src="" id="myLoadingPicture"/>
</form>




    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use an onchange listener on a select element for navigation, as if the user uses keyboard navigation, they will never get past the frist option. IE fires a change event every time a new option is visited, not when one is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show an image before you set the location.href.

```
<select name="URL" onchange="$('#myLoadingPicture').show(); window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value"    onfocus="javascript:toggle();" >
```

Comment: I changed the code in my question to show my whole page and, I'm not sure if I'm anywhere close.. any advice.. The person that posted this suggestion deleted his answer.

Comment: Now try keyboard navigation in IE, you'll not get past the first option before you are taken to another page. If you are using a select element as a navigation menu (which is not a good idea in the first place), don't use the change event.

Comment: @nunespascal I changed the code you edited do I need to do anything else?  Didn't seem to work.

Comment: my page is being viewed in android webview so I'm not to concerned with keyboard navigation.

Comment: No, you should not need to do anything else. But if it doesn't work there, and you must show the image. You can delay setting location.href with a setTimeout. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout]

Comment: @nunespascal  Thanks for help... I put the image in a div and set the style to hidden. That seemed to work. Newbie mistake...

Answer (score 0):

When you start going to another page (more specifically, start unloading a page) then the page is no longer required to respond. Therefore, even if you added an animated GIF (a simple task, just create an image element and append it to the body) there is no guarantee that it will animate, or even show up.